# Wrong controller is called from Form. Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Have a form. 
$this->Form->create(array('controller'=>'bookings','action'=>'book'));

But for some reason, instead of BookingsController it is searching RoomsController for 
the specified action.
Please help. Using Cakephp 2.3

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

```
echo $this->Form->create(
    'Booking',  //notice this - the first item
    array(
        'url' => array(
            'controller'=>'bookings',
            'action'=>'book'
        )
    )
);
```

**Explanation:**

Probably a good idea to look at the documentation instead of just guessing at it's syntax:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

:)